# 'Concatenating' rows of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have a numpy matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

I want to 'concatenate' the rows of the matrix to get a new matrix

```
13 24
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me more like you want to concatenate the columns.  Maybe something like this would suffice?

```
In [25]: import numpy as np

In [26]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,45]])

In [27]: a
Out[27]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3, 45]])

In [28]: [''.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in a.T]
Out[28]: ['13', '245']

In [29]: np.array([''.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in a.T], int)
Out[29]: array([ 13, 245])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. I meant, concatenate all rows in a given column. BTW, I am fine if you don't convert the output back to integer.